# Ler arquivo no HD

Tags: assembly

Onde posso encontrar código em Assembly para ler arquivos no HD?
Por exemplo, no sistema de arquivos FAT32.

Ou então, uma descrição de suas tabelas e organizações para que eu mesmo possa programar.

Uso o NASM como montador, plataforma x8086.
Quero fazer testes com um arquivo de boot que leia arquivos do HD.

Comment: Existem muitas versões de Assembly, favor especificar.

Comment: @bigown já especifiquei.

Comment: O que você já fez?

Comment: @bigown ainda nada, a ideia seria fazer um programa que eu pudesse bootar, e ele carregasse um arquivo do HD na memória para que eu usasse para, por exemplo, apresentar seu conteúdo na tela. Ou então, executasse de forma semelhante ao que o DOS faz com arquivos .com Isto eu sei fazer, só a questão de ler arquivos que é um problema.